# required not working when if is used in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a simple registration form, when I remove the if statements from "from here" comment to "to here" comment, the required works. But, when I the write the if statements, then the required does not work.

```js
function validate() {
    var contact = document.getElementById("Contact").value.search(/^[0-9]{10}/);
    var gender = document.getElementsByName("gender");

    for (var i = 0; i < gender.length; i++) {
        if (gender[i].checked) {
            gender = gender[i].value;
        }
    }

    /*from here*/
    if (contact) {
        alert("Enter correct Contact No.");
    }
    if (gender != "Male" && gender != "Female") {
        alert("Select Gender");
    }
    if (contact == 0 && (gender == "Male" || gender == "Female")) {
        alert("Form submitted!");
    }
    /*to here*/
}
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url("images/back.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

form {
    background-color: white;
    width: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 20px 10px 20px 0px darkgrey;
    margin-top: 6%;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 20px 10px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

tr {
    font-size: 20px;
}

textarea {
    max-width: 250px;
}

h1 {
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #363731;
}

p {
    padding-top: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 40px;
}

#btn {
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
    <p>REGISTRATION</p>
    <form method="post">
        <h1>Add Student</h1>
        <table cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Student Name</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" id="studentName" name="studentName"
                                        size="32" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Contact No</td>
                <td align="left"><input type="number" name="contactNo" id="Contact"
                                        size="32" maxlength="10" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Gender</td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked>Male
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Email Id</td>
                <td align="left">
                    <input type="email" title="Enter valid acharya email" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+\.
        [a-zA-Z]+\.([0-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9])@acharya\.ac\.in" id="email" size="32"
                           required>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Address Line</td>
                <td align="left"><textarea placeholder="Your Address Here..." rows="5"
                                           cols="100"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Add" id="btn"
                                                      onclick="validate()" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Reset" id="btn" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</center>
```

Comment: You're not checking `gender`'s value ... you can like this `!gender.value`.

Comment: There's a button named "tidy" in the snippet editor, please use it, it's fab! It makes code readable...

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your work by moving the if statement about `alert("Form submitted!");` between your two comments and they work out the same result. What part of required check missed? Please specified the issue you're facing, or tell me if I misunderstood your question

And also you should modify some code setting in the line `<form method="post">` to really let the code work

#### EDIT

In order to let the form works you should add a path to send the value to
change the code from `<form method="post">` to something like `<form action="data.php" method="post">`

Code in data.php

```
<h4>Value you submit</h4>
<p>Name <?php echo $_POST["studentName"]; ?></p>
<p>Contact No : <?php echo $_POST["contactNo"]; ?></p>
```

And so one

[Tutorial of handling HTML form by W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Bonus tips:

1) Usually, we use `POST` method because the result can't be seen in address bar but if you want a URL that can be bookmarked and revisit with the same result you should use `GET`

2) I find out you make a required check on gender in your script but I think it's useless since you add a code `checked` in the `Male` option so in that radio part it can't be unchecked, you can only check male or female

Also sorry for my bad English

Comment: I know about the action attribute of the form and the php, I was framing a question for an event in my college. The problem is, when I click add button without entering any data, it gives an alert, but it should have shown "Please fill in this field" near the empty fields.

Answer (score 0):

Required actually works. In your validate function, you are only alerting "Form Submitted" if those validations are met, that does not mean the form has been submitted. If you notice you do not even have a page refresh to show the form has been submitted.

Comment: I don't want to go to another page, just it should alert "form submitted!". The problem was, when I click the add button without entering any data, it shows an alert box, but it should show something like "Please fill in this field", what we generally see with the exclamation mark.